# Decrease the running time of iteration for the fourier coefficient calculation?

Tags: matlab, iteration, signals, signal-processing

The code for the calculation of the fourier coefficient and generation of the original signal is provided below. The problem is that the program runs correctly without any problem but the running time of it to produce the output is too high( nearly 10-15 seconds for N = 25). Is there any way to decrease the running time??

```
function [a,x,t] = square1(N)

j = 0 + i;
L = -N:N;
%a = zeros(size(k));
t = -7:0.01:7;

%Signal Generation
for k = 1:length(t)
    if( t(k) >= -5 & t(k) <= -3) | (t(k) >= -1 & t(k) <= 1) | (t(k) >=3 & t(k) <= 5)
        x(k) = 1;
    else
        x(k) = 0;
    end
end

subplot(3,1,1);
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Value');
title('Continuous Periodic Signal');
plot(t,x);

%Fourier Series Coefficient Plot
a = zeros(size(L));
for k = 1:length(L)
    syms time;
    a(k) = 1/4*int(exp(-j*L(k)*2*pi/4 * time),-1,1);
end
subplot(3,1,2);
stem(L,a);
xlabel('Discrete Value');
ylabel('Fourier Values');
title('Fourier Series Coefficient');

%Generation of the original signal 
time_duration = -10:0.01:10;
y = zeros(size(time_duration));
for m = 1:length(time_duration)
    y(m) = sum(a.*exp(j*L*2*pi/4*time_duration(m)))
end
subplot(3,1,3);
plot(time_duration,y);
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Value');
title('Original Signal Constructed');
```

end

Comment: Matlab has a splendid build in profiler. Just run the profiler with the command you normally use to run your program, and inspect the result to pin point which lines are consuming the most time. Then try to optimize that or those lines. If in doubt how, then update your question with the profile info. Regards

Comment: Tx for suggestion and in my program, the most time consumption lines are the calculation of the fourier series coefficient using the integration and the next one is the synthesis of the original signal using loop(last loop). Can you plz show me a way to optiimize my code in these two loops? Tx in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not near a computer right now, but  I'm certain that the outrageous runtime is due to the use of these symbolic types (syms time). Eliminate the use of those and you will see a speed up of a factor of 100 or more. Of course you will then also have to do your finite integral in a new way, but I don't think there is any way around this. Regards